vertically aligned table in landscape mode with footnotemark
so i have read these:
Footnotes under table in landscape mode
A problem with table in landscape mode
Centering multi-page, long table in landscape pages
and my question is simple:
if i have a "working" table in landscape mode, when using
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\end{table}
how can i preserve that when i change the environment to
\begin{table}[p!]
\end{table}
for the purposes of vertical alignment?
i see that others recommend the threeparttable package with the tablenotes, but it doesn't look as good as i currently have it. i understand these things are more complicated underneath than they appear, but surely there must be some way to get the [p!] mode working with footnotes, when it works fine with [htbp!]?
it seems latex is relying on the 't' to place the footnotes at the bottom.
MWE
\documentclass[onecolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp!]

    \begin{tabular}{lc}
asdfasdf\footnotemark[1] & hiaasdhfhasdf\\
asdfasdfasdf2\footnotemark[2] & asdfasdfasdf\\
\end{tabular}%

\end{table}%
\footnotetext[1]{footie1.}
\footnotetext[2]{footie2.}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


you should always show an example document. table* does not support h  or b  so [htbp] is the same as [tp]  footnotes within a table are lost and not added to the page whether you use t or p.  If you use a minipage within the table* then footnotes will be placed at the end of the minpage (whethe the table is placed via t or p)

example added and tested before posting. simply swap the htbp! to p! to observe the phenomenon being described. behaviour is the same regardless of the asterisked environment (or not). i think there should be something simple for this, but i also acknowledge that if Mico couldn't produce one in a few attempts over the years, then maybe not.

yes so the example makes it clear that you are noit using \footnote  but \footnotemark and then place \footnotetext outside the table on a nearby text page, which was not at all implied by the original question.

i thought it was kind of obvious since you cannot put footnotes in a table environment, that footnotemark was compulsory. it's not outside the page. it's still on the same page when using anything but [p]. but i concede this is the "tex stackexchange" and there are higher standards. i have updated the title appropriately.

also you changed table* to table which rather changes things

i changed that because i wanted to show it didn't matter whether you used table* or table for this particular issew, sire. see edit comments if you care

I raise that as two of the three answers I just posted wouldn't apply in the table* case as you can't have a spanning table mid-page in the default code. If it's a single column document and not using table* spanning table, things are easier,

possible markup

\documentclass[onecolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
asdfasdf\footnotemark[1] & hiaasdhfhasdf\\
asdfasdfasdf2\footnotemark[2] & asdfasdfasdf\\
\end{tabular}%

\footnotetext[1]{footie1.}
\footnotetext[2]{footie2.}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}%

\end{landscape}

\end{document}

or

\documentclass[onecolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \vspace*{\fill}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
asdfasdf\footnotemark[1] & hiaasdhfhasdf\\
asdfasdfasdf2\footnotemark[2] & asdfasdfasdf\\
\end{tabular}%

\end{table}%
\vspace*{\fill}
\footnotetext[1]{footie1.}
\footnotetext[2]{footie2.}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}

or

\documentclass[onecolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \vspace*{\fill}

  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
asdfasdf\footnotemark[1] & hiaasdhfhasdf\\
asdfasdfasdf2\footnotemark[2] & asdfasdfasdf\\
\end{tabular}%


\vspace*{\fill}
\footnotetext[1]{footie1.}
\footnotetext[2]{footie2.}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}


thank you master. "long time reader, first time poster". i have seen your name on plenty of solutions that i use to this day. i love solution #3. that's "Our Way" right there. footnote indent preserved, table centred, everything pretty. i liked the minipage solution too, whilst visually similar to the tablenotes solution, it is simpler and cleaner--also "Our Way". TYVM

i had been trying to use vfill with htbp and ht or whatever, it didn't work. i didn't even think or recall to use vfill* since i haven't found a distinguishing case. this is a good one. MASTER!
